# R language: regexp

Tags: regex, r

I have a character column in a data.frame and I need to find a specific letter after a sequence of numbers.
Problem is that I can't know exactly the position of the specific letter I am looking for.
All that I know is that this specific letter follow a sequence of six numbers.

That's the example:

```
test <– c('ABC150117X01100100', 'ABCD150630Y01000100', 'ABCDE160721Z11001000')
```

In this case the letters I want to find is **X**, **Y** and **Z**.
The function **substr** is not useful, I'm pretty sure that a regular expression may be what I'm looking for. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option:

```
 gsub(".*\\d{6}([A-Za-z]{1}).*","\\1",test)
#[1] "X" "Y" "Z"
```

`\\1` with `gsub` permits to retrieve what is in between the brackets in the `regex`, the `regex` can be detailed as follows:

```
.*            # anything, matched 0 or more times
\\d{6}        # any digit, matched exactly 6 times (i.e. exactly 6 digits)
([A-Za-z]{1}) # what needs to be retrieved, a single letter
.*            # anything, matched 0 or more times
```

*NB: If you can also have in your strings more than 6 digits followed by a letter but you want the letter after exactly 6 digits, you can change the regex for `"(.*\\D\\d{6}|^\\d{6})([A-Z]{1}).*"` and the `gsub` call will be:

`gsub("(.*\\D\\d{6}|^\\d{6})([A-Z]{1}).*","\\2",test)`,

spotting a letter after exactly 6 digits, either at the beginning of the string or after any character that is not a digit.*

Comment: note that this regex works for this particular example. It matches also the letter `Z` in `123456789Z`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, yes, it also matches a letter after 7 or 8 or... digits but the point of my answer was to use gsub, you already provided a "perfect" regex ;-) maybe I can add a note on that

Comment: @AvinashRaj, see my edit, in the alternative `gsub` call, only a letter after exactly 6 digits is extracted. Thank you for your comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex to match the uppercase letter which was preceded by exactly 6 digits.

```
"(?<!\\d)\\d{6}(?!\\d)\\K[A-Z]"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cB8yY1/1)

```
> x <- c("ABC150117X01100100", "ABCD150630Y01000100", "ABCDE160721Z11001000")
> m <- gregexpr("(?<!\\d)\\d{6}(?!\\d)\\K[A-Z]", x, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(x, m)
[[1]]
[1] "X"

[[2]]
[1] "Y"

[[3]]
[1] "Z"
```

`(?<!\\d)\\d{6}(?!\\d)` matches the 6 digit number which isn't preceded and followed by a digit. `\K` discards the matched number. Now the pattern `[A-Z]` matches the following uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=(?<=\\D)\\d{6})[A-Z]
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/22

Somethin like this.

```
 x <- c("ABC150117X01100100", "ABCD150630Y01000100", "ABCDE160721Z11001000")
 m <- gregexpr("(?<=(?<=\\D)\\d{6})[A-Z]", x, perl=TRUE)
 regmatches(x, m)
```